# Git testing branch on google cloud vm will not stay master for other machines

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, branch

Ok so here is the situation.  I have a live website that I want to stay on master for everyone else but me and potentially a co-worker.  The idea is we can work on a testing branch while the site stays live on master.

The site is run on a google cloud vm and we all ssh into one server.  So when I do:

```
sudo git checkout testing
```

and then run the website I see I'm on the testing branch and can see what I'm working on that's different then master.  And conversely if I switch to master I see the website as it should be on master.

Issue:  while I'm working on the testing branch I need the rest of the world that's potentially hitting the site to be on the master branch.   I can't find much online about this?  do I need to make a username and have a command that says only this user ip on testing or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm imagining your VM has a directory eg. /mysite  and in that directory you have performed a git clone of your project.  I am also assuming that the Webserver is reading its content from /mysite.  What this means is that WHATEVER is under /mysite is what will be served.

If you want to do development on your website, then you need a separate environment that is distinct from your primary webserver and distinct from /mysite.

This could be a separate VM or you could create a directory called /mysite_dev and clone your project into that.  You could then checkout testing and do your work there.  Changes made to /mysite_dev is not visible under /mysite and hence not visible to the public.

Comment: So it's served in just the root /var/www/html   but I get what you're saying.  I should make a directory in the root called my_site_dev,  then clode my whole site to it.  Then I can init on that directory and work there?

Comment: And yea we could set up a completely separate VM but then the domain name becomes a problem right?  any call in the code to mysite.com will mess the program up as the testing server is on something like 34.whateveriphere

Comment: At the highest level, I think you want to be following the practice of setting up development, test and production environments.  This is an extremely common practice.  Flipping it around, I think we will find consensus that we should NEVER perform development activities on a production environment.  If you have an environment that is providing live web-site you should NEVER be editing content on that environment ... not even in a separate directory.  Mistakes happen.

Comment: yea, you're right no disputing that.  My goal here is to figure out a way to not be working on a live site.  I thought I had figured it out with the branch thing but guess not.  I cant even push my site up to github so I can clone it and but it in a dev folder.  It's  a huge wordpress site and keeps saying "the remote end hung up unexpectedly".  Well I'll figure this out.